Catia V5 Macro for tree reordering
I've managed to find a code in VBA where a user window will open to allow moving much efficiently the parts in the product tree structure of Catia V5. The only problem with it is that when rearranging the parts if there is any patterns within the product(let's say you have a part with multiple holes and a screw which was patterned to fill all those holes without manually constraining them to the holes) it will break the reuse pattern and will give the error "product holding the initial pattern is missing".
Is there any way to update the code to make it work without destroying the patterns?
This is for the user form
Public Response As Integer
Option Explicit

Private Sub apply_button_Click()
'reorders the tree and stays in the userform
Reorder_Tree

End Sub

Private Sub cancel_button_Click()

'Exit the form when Cancel button is clicked
Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub down_button_Click()

Dim selector As String 'The selected item will be saved here
Dim selected_position As Integer 'The position of the selected item will be saved here
Dim current_occupant As String 'The item one step underneath the selected item will be saved here
'----- variable initialization -----
selector = ""
selected_position = 0
current_occupant = ""
'selected item and its position are determined
selected_position = new_order.ListIndex
selector = new_order.List(selected_position)
'current_occupant is determined
'(IF-statement makes sure nothing happens if item in the very bottom is selected)
If selected_position < (new_order.ListCount - 1) Then
current_occupant = new_order.List(selected_position + 1)
'move the selected item down by one position
new_order.List(selected_position + 1) = selector
new_order.List(selected_position) = current_occupant
'Keep the selected item selected (otherwise the current_occupant,
'that has switched places with selector, will be selected)
new_order.Selected(selected_position + 1) = True

End If

End Sub

Private Sub ok_button_Click()

If new_order.ListCount = 0 Then
Response = MsgBox("There are no items in the list to reorder! Please select at least one component.", , UserForm1.Name & "Warning Message")
Exit Sub
End If

'Reorders the tree and then exits the userform
Reorder_Tree
Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub reset_button_Click()
'this button resets the new_order to the current_order
Dim i As Integer
new_order.Clear
i = 0
For i = 0 To current_order.ListCount - 1
new_order.AddItem current_order.List(i)
Next i

End Sub

Private Sub up_button_Click()

Dim selector As String 'The selected item will be saved here
Dim selected_position As Integer 'The position of the selected item will be saved here
Dim current_occupant As String 'The item one step above the selected item will be saved here
selector = ""
selected_position = 0
current_occupant = ""
'selected item and its position are determined
selected_position = new_order.ListIndex
selector = new_order.List(selected_position)
'current_occupant is determined
'(IF-statement makes sure nothing happens if top-most item is selected)
If selected_position > 0 Then
current_occupant = new_order.List(selected_position - 1)
'move the selected item up by one position
new_order.List(selected_position - 1) = selector
new_order.List(selected_position) = current_occupant
'Keep the selected item selected (otherwise the current_occupant,
'that has switched places with selector, will be selected)
new_order.Selected(selected_position - 1) = True

End If

End Sub

Sub Reorder_Tree()
Dim selection1 As selection
Dim selection2 As selection
Dim ProdName As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer
'---keep assembly constraints when cutting and pasting----------------------
Dim settingControllers1 As SettingControllers
Set settingControllers1 = CATIA.SettingControllers
Dim asmConstraintSettingAtt1 As AsmConstraintSettingAtt
Set asmConstraintSettingAtt1 = settingControllers1.Item("CATAsmConstraintSettingCtrl")
asmConstraintSettingAtt1.PasteComponentMode = catPasteWithCstOnCopyAndCut
'------------------------------------
Set selection1 = productDocument1.selection
'This loop goes through the items in new_order
'and compares them to the components of the selected product.
For j = 0 To UserForm1.new_order.ListCount - 1
'Getting selection1 ready for the operation by clearing whatever might be in it
selection1.Clear
'This for loop goes through the items of the selected product
For i = 1 To product1.Products.Count
ProdName = product1.Products.Item(i).Name
If Left(ProdName, Len(new_order.List(j))) = new_order.List(j) Then
selection1.Add product1.Products.Item(i)
End If
Next i
'cut and paste the components from the original order to the new order
selection1.Cut
Set selection2 = CATIA.ActiveDocument.selection
selection2.Add product1
selection2.Paste
selection1.Clear
selection2.Clear
Next j

End Sub

This is for the modules
Option Explicit
Public productDocument1 As Document 'Holds the active document
Public product1 As product 'Holds the main product
Public products1 As Products 'Holds the list of component parts of product1
Public selection1 As selection 'For looping operations
Public check As Boolean 'For looping operations
Public ip, jp, lp, Response1 As Integer 'for looping operations

Sub CATMain()

    Dim str As String 'Used to save name of element for listing in the ListBox
    Dim instanceIndex As Integer 'Index of the last occurrence of "."
    
    Set productDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument 'productDocument1 set to hold current document
    'products1 set to hold the main product of the active document
    Set product1 = productDocument1.product
    Set products1 = product1.Products 'products1 set to hold the list of components of product1
    
    'loop through all components to add them to the listbox
    For ip = 1 To products1.Count
        check = False
        ' Find the index of the last dot, which denotes the start of the instance
        instanceIndex = InStrRev(products1.Item(ip).Name, ".")
        ' Extract the part number without the instance information
        If instanceIndex > 0 Then
            str = Left(products1.Item(ip).Name, instanceIndex - 1)
        Else
            ' If no instance information found, use the entire name
            str = products1.Item(ip).Name
        End If
        ' Add all component names to the first listbox
        For jp = 0 To UserForm1.current_order.ListCount - 1
            If str = UserForm1.current_order.List(jp) Then
                check = True
                Exit For ' Exit loop if found
            End If
        Next jp
        If check = False Then
            UserForm1.current_order.AddItem str
        End If
    Next ip
    
    ' Finally, populate new_order as well
    UserForm1.new_order.Clear
    For ip = 0 To UserForm1.current_order.ListCount - 1
        UserForm1.new_order.AddItem UserForm1.current_order.List(ip)
    Next ip
    UserForm1.Show

End Sub

Thanks :)
I've tried using the GPT to see if there is any workaround this issue but it come back most of the time with the same responses.
I am expecting when running the macro to not destroy the patters made in the product.

Sorting by cut and paste, like your code does, destroys the links between pattern, parts, ...
You could simulate the manual clicks of the reorder GUI.
This could be done by:

Using the WindowsAPI like shown here (it is written in VB6)
Using the Microsoft UI Automation like shown here

I haven't tried both codes/approaches my self.

Thank you for the responses. The first option I cannot use since we are not allowed to use unauthorized .exe and also the website is blocked by the company, the second option I need to try it again since first time I didn't succeed.
As I understand the second option will run in an excel macro and will prompt Catia.
Please excuse me I am not programmer and some concepts are a little hard for me to understand for the moment :)
